# Lost all permissions to my NTFS partition

Tags: 11.10, permissions, ntfs

I have lost "Write" permission for myself, and all other permissions for 'Others' and 'Group' on my important NTFS Partition(Contains all my Data).
Any amount of Chmod(ing) or using the GUI to set it right isn't working.

I get this error when doing it the GUI way.(No other details of why it couldn't set permissions is mentioned).

[image]

And this happens when doing it in CLI. This is quite an issue need help fast.

[image]

Output of `cat /etc/fstab`

[image]

Output of `dmesg | tail`

[image]

Comment: Please Elaborate more.. Do u mean the contents of "fstab" something like `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'chmod' on an NTFS ( or FAT32 ) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Comment: As you can see, the problem is not permissions, but the 'read only file system'. Something might be wrong with the way you mounted it, or with the file system itself. Run `dmesg | tail` after mounting that partition to find out what's up.

Comment: @Bhargav yes, please update your question with the contents of the file, so we can see how it is mounted.

Comment: @mikewhatever But it was fine until yesterday.. I don't know, I just installed a few programs yesterday, may be one of them would have changed the way it is mounted :(

Comment: It could be that the NTFS partition contains errors. Could you run an error scan from within Windows if it is a Windows partition?

Comment: @lgarzo It is a NTFS partition and yes I can run a error scan from within windows.. Will do it and get back :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got [my answer on ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1892532)

I was using the ntfs driver and not the ntfs-3g driver. I just needed to install the `ntfs-3g` driver and everything worked properly.

Comment: I've edited this to better reflect an answer (so that somebody looking here would know what to do) but it would be best if you could have a quick look and improve this at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your NTFS partition is mounted as read-only. This is the default behaviour when your NTFS partition is auto-mounted.
To solve this issue first identify the device file for your NTFS partition. It will be in /dev directory so the complete file name would be something like /dev/sdaX. You can find this using Disk Utility. After this create a directory in your home directory and unmount your NTFS partition using the following command:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdaX
```

now remount it using the following command to have write access to it:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user /dev/sdaX /home/tintin/DIRECTORY_NAME
```

Comment: Do you want me to create a directory tintin in the home directory?? because my username is bhargav

Comment: Ok here's what I did `sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user /dev/sda5 /home/bhargav/Public` and even then I get this message `mount: warning: /home/bhargav/Public seems to be mounted read-only.` . And I'm not even able to open it :(

Comment: @Bhargav Plz dont mount on /home/bhargav/Public. This is a directory used by the desktop environment so I am not sure what permissions it has and whether it can work or not. Create a new directory in your home folder for example /home/bhargav/VOLUME_LABEL and try mounting on it.

Comment: I did this `sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user /dev/sda5 /home/bhargav/volume.label` as soon as its executed the folder volume.label becomes a folder that can only be accessed with Super User permissions.
The drive is still not accessible and I get this error message.
`The folder contents could not be displayed.
 You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "volume.label".`

Answer (score 0):

I usually mount my ntfs partitions with the options:

**defaults,rw,user,uid=*myusername*,gid=*mygroupname***

Of course this is assuming a single-user system. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Following the basic advice above I created

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user /dev/sda6 /Information
```

so I can mount as wanted. I like it this way because many of the files there are very important to me, so not having automatic access is just another layer of protection.